# How can I round down a number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

How can I round down a number in JavaScript?

`math.round()` doesn't work because it rounds it to the nearest decimal.

I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing it other than breaking it apart at the decimal point at keeping the first bit. There must be...

Comment: Round towards zero or towards negative infinity?

Answer (score 487, accepted):

Using `Math.floor()` is one way of doing this.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Comment: It's also the slowest method; if you need to perform a lot of these, use the bitwise | operator (see my post).

Comment: The | operator also rounds towards zero, not negative infinity.

Answer (score 70):

Round towards negative infinity - `Math.floor()`

```
+3.5 => +3.0
-3.5 => -4.0
```

Round towards zero can be done using [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc). Older browsers do not support this function. If you need to support these, you can use `Math.ceil()` for negative numbers and `Math.floor()` for positive numbers.

```
+3.5 => +3.0 using Math.floor()
-3.5 => -3.0 using Math.ceil()
```

Comment: Thank you for the completeness but the capitalization is wrong ... and in java-script that makes a HUGE difference. Otherwise I would have upvoted here.

Comment: I have updated the answer so that the capitalization is now correct.

Comment: @George HUGE or huge? :D

Comment: You can get the same effect as round-to-zero via `x | 0`.

Answer (score 41):

`Math.floor()` will work, but it's very slow compared to using a bitwise `OR` operation:

```
var rounded = 34.923 | 0;
alert( rounded );
//alerts "34"
```

**EDIT** `Math.floor()` is *not* slower than using the | operator. Thanks to Jason S for checking my work.

Here's the code I used to test:

```
var a = [];
var time = new Date().getTime();
for( i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
    //a.push( Math.random() * 100000  | 0 );
    a.push( Math.floor( Math.random() * 100000 ) );
}
var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - time;
alert( "elapsed time: " + elapsed );
```

Comment: ??? I just ran jsdb (www.jsdb.org) which uses Spidermonkey 1.7, and ran a loop to sum up the floor'ed value of x[i] on an array of 100000 floating point numbers, first with Math.floor(), then with bitwise or as you suggest. It took approx the same time, 125 msec.

Comment: Just repeated the test with 500000 floating point numbers, it took approx the same time, approx 625 msec.

Comment: So I don't see how 1.25usec is very slow.

Comment: Can't argue with your data :) I think I may be have confused JS's implementation with ActionScript's (built on EcmaScript; obviously implementation differs). Thanks for checking my work!

Comment: @Jason S: I don't think .5s is slow to do things, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't aim to be as quick as possible if you have the opportunity.

Comment: They don't do the same thing, either. `|` converts to a 32-bit integer, truncating; `Math.floor` rounds down. http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/UVG2w/

Comment: I agree 100% with minitech's comment.  The main issue is the fact that if the number cannot be represented as a 32-bit number, using this method will result in an unexpected.  On the other hand, if you know beforehand that the number will never be outside of the 32-bit range, you can use this approach instead.

Comment: @Ry- how do you think the processor rounds down internally? :D You guys found 2 sides of the same coin

Comment: @clockw0rk: Converts to a 32-bit integer, truncating: `(-5.8 | 0) === -5`, `(12345678901.2 | 0) === -539222987`; `Math.floor(-5.8) === -6`, `Math.floor(12345678901.2) === 12345678901`. I was pointing out concrete differences in behaviour. (Actually, there’s even a link explaining that in the comment…)

Answer (score 24):

You can try to use this function if you need to round down to a specific number of decimal places

```
function roundDown(number, decimals) {
    decimals = decimals || 0;
    return ( Math.floor( number * Math.pow(10, decimals) ) / Math.pow(10, decimals) );
}
```

examples

```
alert(roundDown(999.999999)); // 999
alert(roundDown(999.999999, 3)); // 999.999
alert(roundDown(999.999999, -1)); // 990
```

Comment: I think a one-liner like this doesn't require a function.

Comment: roundDown(4.56, 2) gives you 4.55, so I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: That's right, because 4.56 * 100 == 455.99999999999994 due to the internal floating point representation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676273/179332

Answer (score 11):

Rounding a `number` towards `0` (aka "truncating its fractional part") can be done by subtracting its *signed* fractional part `number % 1`:

```
rounded = number - number % 1;
```

Like `Math.floor` (rounds towards `-Infinity`) this method is perfectly accurate.

There are differences in the handling of `-0`, `+Infinity` and `-Infinity` though:

```
Math.floor(-0) => -0
-0 - -0 % 1    => +0

Math.floor(Infinity)    => Infinity
Infinity - Infinity % 1 => NaN

Math.floor(-Infinity)     => -Infinity
-Infinity - -Infinity % 1 => NaN
```

Comment: Great answer! Perhaps it should say "Truncating a number towards zero" rather than "Rounding ..."

Answer (score 8):

```
Math.floor(1+7/8)
```

Comment: 1+7/8 = 1 - Not much need for Math.floor() there  :)

Comment: Actually it's (7/8)+1 which is not 1. Thank you 3rd grade algebra

Comment: Umm, please actually try this in a javascript program. I did. Display (1 + 7/8) and you will see 1.875. Math.round(...) is 2, Math.floor(...) is 1. What are you guys talking about?

Comment: Or open the Firefox Error Console. Or Firebug. It isn't hard to try. I tried it. 1 + 7/8 is 1.875 in js. Did you possibly forget that all math in js is in floating point?

Comment: It's probably easy to forget that javascript does everything in floating point. In many *other* languages 1+7/8 is 1, but in js it really is 1.875.

Comment: This has nothing to do with whether javascript uses floating point or not. It all boils down to operator precedence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), so it should always be `1+(7/8)`, being valid in most programming languages

Comment: Actually @DigitalRoss is right. The difference between languages is the data type, not operator precedence. For example SQL returns an integer when doing math operations with integers. `select  1+7/8 /* = 1 */, 7/8 /* = 0 */, 1.0+7.0/8.0 /* = 1.875000 */`. Of course @JasonBerry 's mistake was the operator precedence.

Answer (score 7):

To round down towards negative infinity, use:

```
rounded=Math.floor(number);
```

To round down towards zero (if the number can round to a 32-bit integer between -2147483648 and 2147483647), use:

```
rounded=number|0;
```

To round down towards zero (for any number), use:

```
if(number>0)rounded=Math.floor(number);else rounded=Math.ceil(number);
```

Answer (score 6):

Was fiddling round with someone elses code today and found the following which seems rounds down as well:

```
var dec = 12.3453465,
int = dec >> 0; // returns 12
```

For more info on the Sign-propagating right shift(>>)  see [MDN Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

It took me a while to work out what this was doing :D

But as highlighted above, Math.floor() works and looks more readable in my opinion.

Comment: It also silently kills your number if it doesn't fit in 32 bits. Chromium console:  99999999999999999999999|0 => -167772160

Answer (score 3):

This was the best solution I found that works reliably.

```
function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.floor(parseFloat(value + 'e' + decimals)) + 'e-' + decimals);
 }
```

Credit to: [Jack L Moore's blog](https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 3):

```
Math.round(3.14159 * 100) / 100  // 3.14

3.14159.toFixed(2);              // 3.14 returns a string
parseFloat(3.14159.toFixed(2));  // 3.14 returns a number

Math.round(3.14159)  // 3
Math.round(3.5)      // 4
Math.floor(3.8)      // 3
Math.ceil(3.2)       // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put -1 to round half down and after that multiply by -1 like the example down bellow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function roundNumber(number, precision, isDown) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    var tempNumber = number * factor;
    var roundedTempNumber = 0;
    if (isDown) {
      tempNumber = -tempNumber;
      roundedTempNumber = Math.round(tempNumber) * -1;
    } else {
      roundedTempNumber = Math.round(tempNumber);
    }
    return roundedTempNumber / factor;
  }
</script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <p>Round number 1.25 down: <script>document.write(roundNumber(1.25, 1, true));</script>
  </p>
  <p>Round number 1.25 up: <script>document.write(roundNumber(1.25, 1, false));</script></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly In this community, we prefer answers like @phoebus given above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is math.floor being used in a simple example. This might help a new developer to get an idea how to use it in a function and what it does. Hope it helps!

```
<script>

var marks = 0;

function getRandomNumbers(){    //  generate a random number between 1 & 10
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return number;
}

function getNew(){  
/*  
    This function can create a new problem by generating two random numbers. When the page is loading as the first time, this function is executed with the onload event and the onclick event of "new" button.
*/
document.getElementById("ans").focus();
var num1 = getRandomNumbers();
var num2 = getRandomNumbers();
document.getElementById("num1").value = num1;
document.getElementById("num2").value = num2;

document.getElementById("ans").value ="";
document.getElementById("resultBox").style.backgroundColor = "maroon"
document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML = "***"

}

function checkAns(){
/*
    After entering the answer, the entered answer will be compared with the correct answer. 
        If the answer is correct, the text of the result box should be "Correct" with a green background and 10 marks should be added to the total marks.
        If the answer is incorrect, the text of the result box should be "Incorrect" with a red background and 3 marks should be deducted from the total.
        The updated total marks should be always displayed at the total marks box.
*/

var num1 = eval(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var num2 = eval(document.getElementById("num2").value);
var answer = eval(document.getElementById("ans").value);

if(answer==(num1+num2)){
    marks = marks + 10;
    document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML = "Correct";
    document.getElementById("resultBox").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("totalMarks").innerHTML= "Total marks : " + marks;

}

else{
    marks = marks - 3;
    document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML = "Wrong";
    document.getElementById("resultBox").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("totalMarks").innerHTML = "Total Marks: " + marks ;
}




}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="getNew()">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Let's add numbers</h1>
        <div class="sum">
            <input id="num1" type="text" readonly> + <input id="num2" type="text" readonly>
        </div>
        <h2>Enter the answer below and click 'Check'</h2>
        <div class="answer">
            <input id="ans" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <input id="btnchk" onClick="checkAns()" type="button" value="Check" >
        <div id="resultBox">***</div>
        <input id="btnnew" onClick="getNew()" type="button" value="New">
        <div id="totalMarks">Total marks : 0</div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```