# Rounding up and rounding down bill amount

Tags: javascript, rounding

I'm facing a problem to get the digit of a number after decimal point. I need the digit to do if else statement.

Here is an example:

```
31.30 = 31.30
31.31 = 31.30
31.32 = 31.30
31.33 = 31.35
31.34 = 31.35
31.35 = 31.35
31.36 = 31.35
31.37 = 31.35
31.38 = 31.40
31.39 = 31.30
```

So, I need to get the second digit after decimal point. Then, i can use the digit to do if else statement. This rounding issue is happening in Malaysia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work for doing the rounding to the nearest 5 cents, although then you may need to format the output to have the proper number of digits past the decimal point:

```
var origVal = 31.34;
var roundedVal = Math.round(origVal*20)/20;
```

Which would give you 31.35, i.e., rounded to the nearest nickel.

This seems a little more direct than getting the digit and doing an if/else.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try `Math.round(x*100%10)`

Answer (score 1):

for a part of your question

you can round javascript to specific precision by

[Link :Number rounding in JavaScript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml)

```
var original=28.453


1) //round "original" to two decimals
var result=Math.round(original*100)/100  //returns 28.45



2) // round "original" to 1 decimal
var result=Math.round(original*10)/10  //returns 28.5



3) //round 8.111111 to 3 decimals
var result=Math.round(8.111111*1000)/1000  //returns 8.111
```

from [How can I round down a number in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435975/how-can-i-round-down-a-number-in-javascript?rq=1)

Round towards negative infinity - Math.floor()

+3.5 => +3.0
-3.5 => -4.0
Round towards zero - usually called Truncate(), but not supported by JavaScript - can be emulated by using Math.ceil() for negative numbers and Math.floor() for positive numbers.

+3.5 => +3.0 using Math.floor()
-3.5 => -3.0 using Math.ceil()