# rouding up issue in js

Tags: javascript, rounding

I assumed if the first number after the decimal is 5 or higher, it would rounds up

Here I'm calculating 5% of  31.5.

#### Problem #1

It shouldn't matter which operation happens first but it does

```js
console.log((31.5 * 5)/100) // 1.575

console.log(31.5 * (5/100)) // 1.5750000000000002
```

#### Problem #2

When I round it to 2 decimal point I don't get the same

```js
console.log(((31.5 * 5)/100).toFixed(2)) // 1.57

console.log((31.5 * (5/100)).toFixed(2)) // 1.58
```

Why 1.575 is not rounding up to 1.58?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding up and rounding down bill amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352834/rounding-up-and-rounding-down-bill-amount)

Comment: thanks for the link. so it appears I shouldn't use "toFixed()" and instead use "Math.round()"
I'm assuming there is a bug in toFixed e.g.
let x = 1.575;
Math.round( x * 100)/100  ----> 1.58
but
x.toFixed(2)  ----> 1.57
toFixed would round up to 1.58 if x was 1.5750000000001