# How to truncate floating point number in jscript?

Tags: jscript

How to truncate float value in Jscript?

eg.

```
var x = 9/6
```

Now x contains a floating point number and it is 1.5.
I want to truncate this and get the value as 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I round down a number in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435975/how-can-i-round-down-a-number-in-javascript) (because JScript and JavaScript are very similar)

Comment: @Helen Rounding down and truncating are different things altogether. They do yield the same results with positive numbers, but different with negative numbers.

Comment: @Antti29: The answers in the linked question also explain the difference between rounding down and truncating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = Math.floor(x)
```

This will round the value of x down to the nearest integer below.

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) should achieve what you're looking for, but of course it'll round `1.5` to `2`. If you always want to round down to the nearest integer, use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```
var x = Math.floor(9 / 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor()` only works as the OP intended when the number is positive, as it rounds *down* and not towards zero. Therefore, for negative numbers, `Math.ceil()` must be used.

```
var x = 9/6;
x = (x < 0 ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x));
```

Answer (score -2):

Another solution could be:

```js
var x = parseInt(9 / 6);
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine(x); // returns 1
```

the main purpose of the `parseInt()` function is to parse strings to integers. So I guess it might be slower than `Math.floor()` and methods as such.